# Asset pipeline with ocLazyLoad in angularjs rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on an angularjs-rails app, I want to load some javascript only on specific paths, for that reason I want to install ocLazyLoad.
I have succesfuly installed the module but when I am trying to load a js file I get a 404.

```
 when('/mypath', {
    templateUrl: 'mc/templates/mypath.html',
    controller: 'MyPathController',
    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                name: 'mypath',
                files: [
                    'javascript/mypath.js'
                ] 
            }]);
        }]
    }
  })
```

Comment: just return `$ocLazyLoad.load( 'javascript/mypath.js');`

Comment: It doesn't work, I have to connected with asset pipeline but I don't know how.